# Should I use scan or query?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, claudiajs

I'm having a tough time in DynamoDB with selecting a group of entries between two dates.  My dates are strings and formatted simply as "2018-01-01".

Should I be using query or scan?  Do my params look ok?  The operation seems to work, but I get no results back.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
// get transactions for {month} and {year}
api.get('/transaction/tab/{year}/{month}', (request) => {
  const year = request.pathParams.year
  const month = request.pathParams.month
  const params = {
    TableName: request.env.tableName,
    KeyConditionExpression: '#date between :val1 and :val2',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#date': 'date'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':val1': {
        S: year +'-' + month + '-01'
      },
      ':val2': {
        S: year + '-' + month + '-' + getDaysInMonth(month, year)
      }
    }
  }
console.log(params)
  // post-process dynamo result before returning
  dynamoDb.query(params, (err, data) => {
    console.log(data)
    if (err) {
      console.error('Unable to query. Error:', JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
      return 'Unable to query. Error: '+ JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)
    } else {
      console.log('Query succeeded.')
      data.Items.forEach((item) => {
        console.log(' -', item.year + ': ' + item.title)
      })
      return data.Items
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `KeyConditionExpression` expression that mean you have use `Query` on a `GSI`.

If `date` is the partition key and not the sort key. Then, you have a problem:

You do not define `IndexName` in your params.

In a Query operation, you cannot perform a comparison test (<, >, BETWEEN, ...) on the partition key. The condition must perform an equality test (=) on a single partition key value and, optionally, one of several comparison tests on a single sort key value.

For example:

`KeyConditionExpression: 'HashKey = :hkey and RangeKey > :rkey'`

Are you want to get `transactions` of a month? I think, you have to create a GSI with: `year-month` is PrimaryKey(ex: 2018-01, 2018-02), `day-createdAt` is SortedKey (ex: 28-1535429111358, ...)

The query will be like above:

```
const params = {
    TableName: request.env.tableName,
    IndexName: 'MONTH-DAY-IDX',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'year-month = :val1',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':val1': {
        S: year +'-' + month
      },
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I'm wanting to get a list of transactions in a month.  So, you're proposing to store the date as separate fields?

I already have a `created` and `updated` entries as a part of the data model.  This is the date of the transaction.  It's kind of like a register.  This will be a flexible, user-entered value.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB doesn't support natively `date/time` type. So I would suggest to store date as UTC `Number`, aka  `Unix epoch time` and use `Query` as it is much better than `Scan`

Have a quick look at the following article to know how to convert to unix timestamps:

https://coderwall.com/p/rbfl6g/how-to-get-the-correct-unix-timestamp-from-any-date-in-javascript

Comment: Yeah, I've considered that.  Might be what I end up with.